# Is there an option in dax to order by ordinal position

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas

Do we have an option in DAX to order by ordinal position? based on the documentations, It does not look like we have one.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-sort-by-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are asking whether you can do `ORDER BY 2`? I do not believe that is accepted syntax per [dax.guide](https://dax.guide/st/order-by/). Accepted syntax is:

```
EVALUATE
ALL (
    'Product'[Brand],
    'Product'[Color]
)
ORDER BY
    'Product'[Brand] ASC,
    'Product'[Color] DESC
```